# Solr search within a sentence

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

Is there a way for tokenization/searching just within a sentence?

For example

good w/s Friday
will produce hit on [`Today is good Friday`].  But not on [`Today is Friday. Good!`]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built-in. One way is to add large gaps (lets say 1000) between sentences during indexing and doing a spannearquery with your terms and a slope of 1000.